# Arithmetic overflow error for smalldatetime

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, smalldatetime

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, ClientVisit.rev_timeout, ClientVisit.signature_datetime) = 3  THEN
   CASE WHEN ClientVisit.multiple_flag = 1 
        THEN ClientVisit.rev_timein 
        ELSE ClientVisit.clientvisit_id END 
      END
```

**Datatypes**

- rev_timeout - smalldatetime
- rev_timein - smalldatetime
- signature_datetime - datetime
- multiple_flag - bit
- clientvisit_id - int.

**Error**

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smalldatetime

SQL Server is converting `clientvisit_id` to *smalldatetime* and I'm not sure why since I don't see a comparison with another datetime here. Just a count increment when the `DATEDIFF returns a 3`. Could someone explain why this is happening and a solution?

Comment: what is the total error:Arithmetic overflow error converting  "what " to datatype smalldatetime

Comment: Edited: expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** that ultimately returns a single, atomic value. Therefore, all parts of a `CASE` expression *should return* the same datatype.

This is *not* the case here! The inner `CASE` returns

```
THEN ClientVisit.rev_timein
```

which is of datatype `smalldatetime`, while the `ELSE` part:

```
ELSE ClientVisit.clientvisit_id
```

returns a value of datatype `int`.

T-SQL will try to convert those values [according to this data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) list and thus tries to convert the `int` to a `smalldatetime` and fails.

**What to learn**: `CASE` is an **expression** which should return **the same datatype** from all it's `THEN` and `ELSE` branches ...

Comment: So I'll have to cast or convert all the date times to int to make this work? Will that not affect the date functions and comparisons?

Comment: @AmulyaSharma: why are you returning a `smalldatetime` in one case, and an `int` in another?? Just make sure you return **the same datatype** for all different possible return values